# Ratio of two functions leads to different limit than expected

Tags: plotting, functions

Here, `numerator` seems to go like `x^8` and `denominator` as `x^12` so the ratio `f[x_] := numerator/denominator` should scale as `x^-4` for small `x`. But as can be seen here `LogLogPlot[{x^{-2}, f[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]`, it scales as `x^-2`. What am I missing here?

```
    numerator={{0.00286145 x^8 - 0.0265613 x^9 + 2.46093*10^13 x^10 - 
       3.11621*10^14 x^11 + 2.16468*10^15 x^12 - 1.09216*10^16 x^13 + 
       4.45768*10^16 x^14 - 1.55566*10^17 x^15 + 4.79618*10^17 x^16 - 
       1.33369*10^18 x^17 + 3.39153*10^18 x^18 - 7.9633*10^18 x^19 + 
       1.73846*10^19 x^20 - 3.54692*10^19 x^21 + 6.78959*10^19 x^22 - 
       1.22299*10^20 x^23 + 2.07754*10^20 x^24 - 3.33383*10^20 x^25 + 
       5.05989*10^20 x^26 - 7.27038*10^20 x^27 + 9.89767*10^20 x^28 - 
       1.27758*10^21 x^29 + 1.56476*10^21 x^30 - 1.82011*10^21 x^31 + 
       2.01273*10^21 x^32 - 2.11864*10^21 x^33 + 2.126*10^21 x^34 - 
       2.03727*10^21 x^35 + 1.86778*10^21 x^36 - 1.64143*10^21 x^37 + 
       1.38513*10^21 x^38 - 1.12378*10^21 x^39 + 8.77071*10^20 x^40 - 
       6.58173*10^20 x^41 + 4.74105*10^20 x^42 - 3.26862*10^20 x^43 + 
       2.14783*10^20 x^44 - 1.338*10^20 x^45 + 7.85029*10^19 x^46 - 
       4.30352*10^19 x^47 + 2.1825*10^19 x^48 - 1.01072*10^19 x^49 + 
       4.19696*10^18 x^50 - 1.52*10^18 x^51 + 4.58693*10^17 x^52 - 
       1.068*10^17 x^53 + 1.84911*10^16 x^54 - 6.48432*10^15 x^55 + 
       7.47703*10^15 x^56 - 7.00831*10^15 x^57 + 4.86855*10^15 x^58 - 
       2.71354*10^15 x^59 + 1.27209*10^15 x^60 - 5.14394*10^14 x^61 + 
       1.81845*10^14 x^62 - 5.65755*10^13 x^63 + 1.55288*10^13 x^64 - 
       3.75818*10^12 x^65 + 7.9955*10^11 x^66 - 1.48751*10^11 x^67 + 
       2.40162*10^10 x^68 - 3.32997*10^9 x^69 + 3.90973*10^8 x^70 - 
       3.81318*10^7 x^71 + 3.00724*10^6 x^72 - 184308. x^73 + 
       8238.06 x^74 - 238.922 x^75 + 3.375 x^76}};

denominator={{6.05121*10^12 x^12 - 6.5859*10^13 x^13 + 4.24742*10^14 x^14 - 
   2.1036*10^15 x^15 + 8.75327*10^15 x^16 - 3.19789*10^16 x^17 + 
   1.0524*10^17 x^18 - 3.17183*10^17 x^19 + 8.85641*10^17 x^20 - 
   2.31027*10^18 x^21 + 5.66567*10^18 x^22 - 1.31253*10^19 x^23 + 
   2.88314*10^19 x^24 - 6.02277*10^19 x^25 + 1.19927*10^20 x^26 - 
   2.28053*10^20 x^27 + 4.14747*10^20 x^28 - 7.22192*10^20 x^29 + 
   1.20509*10^21 x^30 - 1.9282*10^21 x^31 + 2.95965*10^21 x^32 - 
   4.35905*10^21 x^33 + 6.16103*10^21 x^34 - 8.35621*10^21 x^35 + 
   1.08742*10^22 x^36 - 1.3574*10^22 x^37 + 1.6248*10^22 x^38 - 
   1.86426*10^22 x^39 + 2.0494*10^22 x^40 - 2.15748*10^22 x^41 + 
   2.17385*10^22 x^42 - 2.09522*10^22 x^43 + 1.93054*10^22 x^44 - 
   1.69938*10^22 x^45 + 1.42812*10^22 x^46 - 1.14493*10^22 x^47 + 
   8.74938*10^21 x^48 - 6.3678*10^21 x^49 + 4.40966*10^21 x^50 - 
   2.90255*10^21 x^51 + 1.81397*10^21 x^52 - 1.07505*10^21 x^53 + 
   6.03389*10^20 x^54 - 3.20263*10^20 x^55 + 1.60498*10^20 x^56 - 
   7.58105*10^19 x^57 + 3.36874*10^19 x^58 - 1.40535*10^19 x^59 + 
   5.49155*10^18 x^60 - 2.00506*10^18 x^61 + 6.82183*10^17 x^62 - 
   2.15635*10^17 x^63 + 6.31174*10^16 x^64 - 1.70453*10^16 x^65 + 
   4.22969*10^15 x^66 - 9.59993*10^14 x^67 + 1.98249*10^14 x^68 - 
   3.70274*10^13 x^69 + 6.21103*10^12 x^70 - 9.27952*10^11 x^71 + 
   1.22253*10^11 x^72 - 1.40282*10^10 x^73 + 1.38027*10^9 x^74 - 
   1.14091*10^8 x^75 + 7.7039*10^6 x^76 - 408038. x^77 + 
   15896.3 x^78 - 405. x^79 + 5.0625 x^80}};
```

Comment: It is because you take a large interval `[0,1]`. Both functions, denominator, and numerator,  have lots of terms. The terms of the order higher than that of the first one make a non-negligible contribution visible within this interval. If you plot it within a smaller interval, say, `[0,10^-6]` you will see that it goes like `x^-4`.

Comment: As a side note, it is not a good idea to work with high-order polynomials with machine-precision coefficients. The loss of precision due to cancellation is terrible.

Comment: Thanks, @Roman, and Alexei Boulbitch. Intuitively, one would expect that these higher-order terms should not contribute in the limit $x\to 0$. Is there a better way to obtain the limiting behavior?

Answer (score 2):

A plot is not the appropriate tool to see small differences. Consider:

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Well, it is of the order 1/x^4, but the coefficient is very small. Why is that? Consider the coefficients of the lowest order terms of numerator and denominator and their ratio:

```
0.00286145`/(6.05121*10^12)

4.72872*10^-16
```

The same goes for the 1/x^3 term. Only the 1/x^2 term has a substantial coefficient. Therefore, the plot will look similar to 1/x^2.